# How to accept values on pressing "Enter" only if all fields are full?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyboard-events

So I have this code in place that accepts 2 fields "userNAme" and "yourMessage". The "Send" button only activates if both the fields are filled up.

```js
$("input[type='text'],textarea").keyup(function() {
  var text = ($(this).val()).toString();
  text = text.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim();
  var message = ($("textarea").val()).toString();
  message = message.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim();
  if (text != "" && message != "") {
    $('input[type="button"]').removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $("#send").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hello!</h1>
<form action="" method="post" id="subscribe" name="subscribe">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Name" autofocus><br>
  <div id="message"></div>
  Your Message:<br>
  <textarea typeof="text" id="yourMessage" placeholder="Start Typing..."></textarea><br />
  <input type="button" class="button button-blue" value="Send" name="button" disabled="disabled" id="send" />
</form>
<input type="button" class="button button-blue" value="Click Me!" id="click-me" />
<div id="message"></div>
```

But now I want to add the functionality of Entering the values on key press of "Enter". I want this to work like the "Send" button, i.e. only work if all fields are filled up. How to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the `required` attribute into your `input` tag when you click on Submit or hit the Enter key, all fields must be already completed in order to be submited.

For example:

`<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Name" required autofocus>`

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks @AlcaeusD

Answer (score 0):

if you were to use a `button` with type `submit` the form will not be submitted by pressing enter as long as that button is disabled, like below

```js
$("input[type='text'],textarea").keyup(function() {
  var text = ($(this).val()).toString();
  text = text.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim();
  var message = ($("textarea").val()).toString();
  message = message.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim();
  if (text != "" && message != "") {
    $('button[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $("#send").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hello!</h1>
<form action="" method="post" id="subscribe" name="subscribe">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Name" autofocus><br>
  <div id="message"></div>
  Your Message:<br>
  <textarea typeof="text" id="yourMessage" placeholder="Start Typing..."></textarea><br />
  <button type="submit" class="button button-blue" name="button" disabled="disabled" id="send">Send</button>
</form>
<input type="button" class="button button-blue" value="Click Me!" id="click-me" />
<div id="message"></div>
```

Comment: my jquery does not seem to pick up the button setting it to submit type, as it fails to enable it even after all fields are filled up. Thanks! @zola